# C++ cashier code

Tags: c++

**The question:**

> Giving change. Implement a program that directs a cashier  how to give
>   change. The program has two inputs: the  amount due and the amount
>   received from the customer.  Display the dollars, quarters, dimes,
>   nickels, and pennies  that the customer should receive in return.

**What i have so far:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
double amount_due;
double amount_recieved;

cout << "Enter amount due: " << endl;
cin >> amount_due;
cout << "Enter amount received: ";
cin >> amount_recieved;

int change = amount_recieved - amount_due;
int dollar = 100;
int quarters = 25;
int dimes = 10;
int nickels = 5;
int pennies = 1;



//Return change in full dollars

cout << "dollars: " << change % 100  << endl;


//Return change in quarters

cout << "quarters:  " << (change % 100) % 25 << endl;

//Return change in dimes

cout << "dimes: " << ((change % 100) % 25) % 10 << endl;

// Return change in nickels

cout << "nickels: " << (((change % 100) % 25) % 10) % 5 << endl;

//Return change in pennies

cout << "pennies:  " << ((((change % 100) % 25) % 10) % 5) % 1 << endl;



system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

I realize there are some other one of these answered but they may be to advanced to use in my code, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: So if you give out `change%100` in dollars, how much change is left to give out in quarters and below?  It can't be `change%100` again, right?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of declaring the change values? Is this all you want to do? Or do you have use for those variables at some point? What happens when you run the code right now?

Comment: yea i see what your saying how should i go about doing it?

Comment: How would you do this if you were not writing a program?

Comment: im a total c++ noob basically i just need to be able to give change

Comment: `im a total c++ noob basically`  This has nothing really to do with C++.  You need to write down the steps to give change, regardless of whether you're writing a program or not.  That's how you solve the problem -- solve it on paper first.

Comment: when i run the code now it gives me correct dollars but everything else is wrong

Comment: @user3400146 - Forget the program for a moment.  Take a real life example.  Something costs 10.35 and I give you a 20 dollar bill.  What steps do you do to give me the change?  What operations and steps would be done?  I think the problem is that you're trying to write everything in one formula.  Programming requires you to think in discrete steps, and I don't think you're doing that.

Comment: well i would just subtract 10.35 from 20, get 9.65 and then go from there

Comment: @user3400146 - ok, so where did you subtract in your program?  You didn't.

Comment: @user3400146 Break it down even further. You subtract `20 - 10.35`, get `9.65`, and have to give that back in change. You give back `$5`, then subtract that from `9.65` leaving you with `4.65` still to give. You give back `$4` in ones and subtract that from `4.65`, leaving you with `0.65` still to give. You give back `0.50` in quarters and subtract that from `0.65`, leaving you with `0.15` to give. You give `0.10` in dimes and subtract that from `0.15`, leaving you with `0.05`, or a single nickel, to give.

Comment: @user3400146 It's an iterative process. Give back the biggest amount in a *single* bill/coin that you can, subtract it from what you still have to give, and repeat until you reach 0.

Comment: Why are amount_due and amount_received doubles when a quarter is 25 instead of .25? It would make more sense to me to use ints or longs.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is the same as a cashier would do.

First ensure the change is represented as whole pennies.

Then provide enough dollars until the change remaining is less than a dollar. Then move on to quarters, then dimes, nickels and pennies.

So for the dollar case, pseudo-code would be:

```
dollars = change / 100        # get integral number of dollars
change = change % 100         # and reduce change-left-to-go accordingly
print dollars, " dollars"
```

It should then be a simple matter to apply that logic to the other coin types in order of reducing value.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems. The first is that you ask the user to input values, but don't specify what they are. If the user enters a number that's not in pennies, you're not going to get the value you expect. I expect this input should be in dollars. So, first, change `change` into:

```
change =  int((amount_recieved - amount_due) * 100.0)
```

Next:

```
 cout << "dollars: " << change % 100 << end;
```

Will return the remainder of dividing change by 100, which is not what you want. You simply want to divide dollars by 100. You also want to likely modify change to stop you having to repeat this math.

```
 dollars = change / 100;
 cout << "dollars: " << dollars << endl;
 change -= dollars*100;
```

From there, the rest of the code should work as expected minus the `% 100` parts. As others have mentioned in the comments to the question, your problem is arising from not thinking the math through first, not from doing anything inherently wrong with C++. This would have produced the wrong result in any language, including writing it down as math on a blackboard.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you are not doing the step required to get this working, and that is repeated subtraction.  Yes, you subtracted the price from the amount given, and determined the dollars to give, but you failed to subtract out those dollars, giving you a new total to determine how many quarters.

Something like this (assuming you're working in pennies):

```
    change_left = customer_payment - original_cost;

    //...
    number of dollars = change_left  / 100;
    change_left = change_left - (100 * number of dollars);  <-- where is this?
```

Now how do you determine the number of quarters?  You have a "running total" called change_left that is being reduced by the change you currently have given the customer.  You repeat similar steps to get the number of quarters, then number of dimes, nickels, etc., i.e. divide by 25, then subtract out the number of quarters giving a new "change_left".  Then repeat for 10 to get the dimes, 5 to get the number of nickels, etc.

So again, the problem isn't C++ -- the issue is that you are not thinking this out as a discrete series of steps that lead to a final goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
double amount_due;
double amount_recieved;

cout << "Enter amount due: " << endl;
cin >> amount_due;
cout << "Enter amount received: ";
cin >> amount_recieved;

int change = amount_recieved - amount_due;
int dollar = 100;
int quarters = 25;
int dimes = 10;
int nickels = 5;
int pennies = 1;

//Return change in full dollars

cout << "dollars: " << change / 100  << endl;    

//Return change in quarters

cout << "quarters:  " << (change % 100) / 25 << endl;

//Return change in dimes

cout << "dimes: " << ((change % 100) % 25) / 10 << endl;

// Return change in nickels

cout << "nickels: " << (((change % 100) % 25) % 10) / 5 << endl;

//Return change in pennies

cout << "pennies:  " << ((((change % 100) % 25) % 10) % 5) / 1 << endl;

return 0;
}
```